# How to setup a shared ccache

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, build-process

How can I setup a shared ccache without falling into a permissions problem?

I would like to run a nightly or CI build with latest changes and share all created binaries throughout the R&D using a large ccache repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution: create a new group (e.g. "devel"), and make all developers members of it.  Give read/write permissions to that group on the directory hierarchy where the cache is maintained.  The developers will also need to fix their umask.

Comment: How it will work for people using multiple systems?

Comment: What does "developers will also need to fix their umask" mean? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 12):

See the newly written [Sharing a cache](https://ccache.dev/manual/3.7.11.html#_sharing_a_cache) section in ccache's manual. In essence, use the same `CCACHE_DIR` setting, set `CCACHE_UMASK` appropriately and consider using `CCACHE_BASEDIR`.

Comment: What does "set CCACHE_UMASK appropriately" mean? What does it mean to "consider using CCACHE_BASEDIR"?

Answer (score 3):

You might also take a look at Mozilla's [sccache](https://github.com/mozilla/sccache), which is a ccache-like tool that can store build artifacts in cloud storage (GCS/S3/Azure or redis/memcached).

Answer (score 0):

If you also use the related [distcc](http://distcc.samba.org/), then the permission problems would largely go away, as the compilations would be run under it's control on whatever compile-farm hosts you set.

You could also include the developers desktop machines among the distcc hosts, though at the expense of having some duplicated work where a file would potentially be compiled on more than one machine - though it would never return an out of date compiled object file. It would also speed up day to day recompilations.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [xcache](https://github.com/alibaba/xcache).
It's ccache-cloud and has been used in alibaba which has high efficiency.
If you are using ccache, it would be very easy to switch to xcache.